# Is it possible to use a variable in a list of integers?

Tags: python

I am trying to use `random.choices` with weights but I sometimes have to tweak the weights a bit. Since I have a lot of repeated weights I thought I might just make a variable and set it as one of the weights.

This is what I tried:

```
uncommon = 10
print("".join(random.choices(hahafunnyrandom, weights=(110, ([uncommon] * 6), 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.001))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`weights` must contain numbers only, but `[uncommon] * 6` is a list, so one of your weights is a *list* of 6 elements, which won't work.

You can unpack this list into the tuple of weights:

```
weights=(110, *([uncommon] * 6), 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.001)
```

For example:

```
>>> uncommon = 9
>>> weights=(110, *([uncommon] * 6), 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.001)
>>> weights
(110, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.001)
```

Comment: i have no clue what you mean

Comment: @Undergod Note the `*` before the expression `([uncommon] * 6)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuple concatenation:

```py
>>> uncommon = 9
>>> (110,) + (uncommon,) * 6 + (5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.001)
(110, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.001)
```